# Element being oddly stretched out after I removed "float:right"

Tags: css

**EDIT:** The first problem (positioning) has been solved but the stretching out problem still remains and can be reproduced https://jsfiddle.net/ZeHgS/ove9afg7/3/ here by adding/removing "float:right" from ".woo-cat-toggle" at the very bottom of the CSS. The problem can be seen in the snippet here also.

**SITUATION**

I am a beginner at CSS and haven't been able to adapt something that I got from github.

This is the page I am having trouble with

https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=feminino

Here is the snippet. I have no idea why two toggle icons appear here on Stack. Only one appears on my site

```js
jQuery(function($){
    // add a new toggle element Before the parent category anchor
    // /*Use the following line to have more levels collapse:*/
  $( "<div class='woo-cat-toggle'></div>" ).insertAfter( "#secondary .widget_product_categories .product-categories .cat-item.cat-parent > a" );
    // when the new toggle element is clicked, add/remove the class that controls visibility of children
    $( "#secondary .widget_product_categories .product-categories .woo-cat-toggle" ).click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("cat-popped");
    });
    // if the parent category is the current category or a parent of an active child, then show the children categories too
    /*$('#secondary .widget_product_categories .product-categories > .cat-item.cat-parent').each(function(){*/
  /*Same for having more levels collapse and detect the active category*/
  $('#secondary .widget_product_categories .product-categories .cat-item.cat-parent').each(function(){
        if($(this).is('.current-cat, .current-cat-parent')) {
            $(this).children('.woo-cat-toggle').toggleClass("cat-popped");
        } 
    });
});
```

```css
/* - woo cat toggling elements, injected via jQuery - */

/* make list item be relative, to be able to position toggle within this item, if desired */
#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent {
    position: relative; 
}
/* the new toggle element wrapper, which is added via jQuery */
#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
    line-height: 1em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left:10px;
}
/* when it's popped, style the toggle wrapper differently */
#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle.cat-popped {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: rgba(0,24,113,1);
    color: white;
    overflow:visible;
  margin-left:10px;
}
/* toggle icon */
#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle::before {
    display:inline;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: none;
    speak: none;
    content: '+';
    line-height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* toggle icon when triggered */
#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle.cat-popped::before {
    content: '\2013';
    
}
/* hide sub cats by default */
#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle ~ ul.children {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
/* show sub cats when triggered via jQuery toggle */
#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle.cat-popped ~ ul.children {
    max-height: 1000000px;
}

/* WHEN THIS IS COMMENTED OUT, THE ICON STRETCHES THE REASON THIS WAS PRESENT IS THAT THE PLACE I TOOK THE CODE FROM HAD ALL ICONS NEATLY ALIGNED TO THE RIGHT BUT I WANT THEM NEXT TO THE LINKS AS IT IS NOW.
.woo-cat-toggle {
    float:right;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
   <!--dynamic_sidebar_before:sidebar-1:1-->
   <div data-customize-partial-id="widget[woof_widget-2]" data-customize-partial-type="widget" data-customize-partial-placement-context="{&quot;sidebar_id&quot;:&quot;sidebar-1&quot;,&quot;sidebar_instance_number&quot;:1}" data-customize-widget-id="woof_widget-2" id="woof_widget-2" class="widget WOOF_Widget" title="Shift-click to edit this widget.">
      <span class="customize-partial-edit-shortcut customize-partial-edit-shortcut-widget-woof_widget-2">
         <button aria-label="Click to edit this widget." title="Click to edit this widget." class="customize-partial-edit-shortcut-button">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
               <path d="M13.89 3.39l2.71 2.72c.46.46.42 1.24.03 1.64l-8.01 8.02-5.56 1.16 1.16-5.58s7.6-7.63 7.99-8.03c.39-.39 1.22-.39 1.68.07zm-2.73 2.79l-5.59 5.61 1.11 1.11 5.54-5.65zm-2.97 8.23l5.58-5.6-1.07-1.08-5.59 5.6z"></path>
            </svg>
         </button>
      </span>
      <div class="widget widget-woof" title="Shift-click to edit this widget.">
         <span class="gamma widget-title">Filtrar produtos</span>
         <div class="woof woof_sid woof_sid_widget " data-sid="widget" data-shortcode="woof sid='widget' mobile_mode='0' autosubmit='-1' start_filtering_btn='0' price_filter='0' redirect='' ajax_redraw='0' btn_position='b' dynamic_recount='-1' " data-redirect="" data-autosubmit="1" data-ajax-redraw="0">
            <!--- here is possible to drop html code which is never redraws by AJAX ---->
            <div class="woof_redraw_zone" data-woof-ver="2.2.6.2">
               <div class="woof_submit_search_form_container">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-customize-partial-id="widget[woocommerce_product_categories-2]" data-customize-partial-type="widget" data-customize-partial-placement-context="{&quot;sidebar_id&quot;:&quot;sidebar-1&quot;,&quot;sidebar_instance_number&quot;:1}" data-customize-widget-id="woocommerce_product_categories-2" id="woocommerce_product_categories-2" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories" title="Shift-click to edit this widget.">
      <span class="customize-partial-edit-shortcut customize-partial-edit-shortcut-widget-woocommerce_product_categories-2">
         <button aria-label="Click to edit this widget." title="Click to edit this widget." class="customize-partial-edit-shortcut-button">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
               <path d="M13.89 3.39l2.71 2.72c.46.46.42 1.24.03 1.64l-8.01 8.02-5.56 1.16 1.16-5.58s7.6-7.63 7.99-8.03c.39-.39 1.22-.39 1.68.07zm-2.73 2.79l-5.59 5.61 1.11 1.11 5.54-5.65zm-2.97 8.23l5.58-5.6-1.07-1.08-5.59 5.6z"></path>
            </svg>
         </button>
      </span>
      <span class="gamma widget-title">Categorias</span>
      <ul class="product-categories">
         <li class="cat-item cat-item-220 cat-parent">
            <a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=acessorios&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Acessórios</a>
            <div class="woo-cat-toggle"></div>
            <ul class="children">
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-221"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=acessorios-para-sapatos-joias-relogios&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Acessórios para Sapatos/Joias/Relógios</a></li>
               <li class="cat-item cat-item-222 cat-parent">
                  <a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=bolsas-malas-mochilas&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Bolsas/Malas/Mochilas</a>
                  <div class="woo-cat-toggle"></div>
                  <ul class="children">
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-224"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=bolsas&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Bolsas</a></li>
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-225"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=bolsas-carteiro&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Bolsas Carteiro</a></li>
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-226"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=bolsas-e-pastas-para-notebook&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Bolsas e Pastas para Notebook</a></li>
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-227"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=carteiras-porta-cartoes-organizadores&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Carteiras/Porta-Cartões/Organizadores</a></li>
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-228"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=guarda-chuvas&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Guarda-Chuvas</a></li>
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-229 cat-parent">
                        <a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=malas-de-viagem&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Malas de Viagem</a>
                        <div class="woo-cat-toggle"></div>
                        <ul class="children">
                           <li class="cat-item cat-item-230"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=bolsas-sacola&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Bolsas Sacola</a></li>
                           <li class="cat-item cat-item-231"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=conjuntos-de-malas&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Conjuntos de Malas</a></li>
                           <li class="cat-item cat-item-232"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=malas&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Malas</a></li>
                           <li class="cat-item cat-item-233"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=malas-de-bordo&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Malas de Bordo</a></li>
                           <li class="cat-item cat-item-234"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=mochilas-de-rodinhas-infantis&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Mochilas de Rodinhas Infantis</a></li>
                           <li class="cat-item cat-item-235"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=porta-ternos-para-viagem&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Porta-Ternos para Viagem</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-236"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=mochilas&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Mochilas</a></li>
                     <li class="cat-item cat-item-237"><a href="https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/?product_cat=pochetes&customize_changeset_uuid=7116f1b4-3388-4888-af57-ec9284bbde1d&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1&customize_autosaved=on">Pochetes</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <!--dynamic_sidebar_after:sidebar-1:1-->
</div>
```

**OBJECTIVE**

I want round icons to the immediate right of the categories names they represent, for every category level.

**PROBLEM**

If I don't comment out the very last section of the CSS that assigns "float: right", all of these appear in alignment, which I don't want, but perfectly round, which I do want, like so:

[image]

And if I remove the float property it distorts and stretches vertically but the position becomes correct.

[image]

So I want a mixture of the two. I want the position to be as it is without "float:right" except 10px to the right but I want the shape that it has when "float:right" is not commented out (a circle).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please edit the question and add html and css as a snippet that reproduces the behavior. There is a tool for it in the editor. As a side note, why float right if you want the element to be after the text, does not make any sense. You also seem to have negative margin-left which is why the element goes over the text. Clean up your css and remove all unnecessary things.

Comment: Could you reduce the code and post an example with HTML and css?

From the looks of it, your button element doesn't have a width attribute. Double check if you assigned width and height on the element.
```.widget_product_categories ul li a::before``` seems to be your toggle element, which doesn't have any width or height property. But, ```#secondary .widget_product_categories ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent .woo-cat-toggle::before``` has width and height properties.

Comment: Thank you both for replying! Forgive me, I didn't know this functionality existed. I tried pasting my whole category tree but it was 5 times larger than the maximum number of characters so I removed a bunch of items but now for some reason it doesn't look like ti should. Thanks Lalalena, I will try to see if that's the cause and let you know

Comment: I tried pasting "width:15px;height:15px" into every field and nothing happened but Esko was right that there was a negative left margin and now the position looks perfect on my website. All that I am having problems with right now is the vertical stretching

Comment: You have your `.woo-cat-toggle` set to `display: inline`, which means `width` and `height` are ignored. Make that `inline-block` instead.

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thank you so much. If you answer I'll mark it as the right one